# 3DPlot of function gives back wrong function?

Tags: tikz-3dplot, intersections

I do not understand why the function `{x^3}` in my plot is not an elliptic but somehow linear. For `y^3` it worked out fine. Did I miss sth.? Or do you have a better idea for an elliptic function which intersect with the other?

```
   \documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=7cm,compat=1.8}
\begin{document} 
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[grid=major,view={210}{30},
ymin=0,
 ymax=10,
 xmin=0,
 xmax=10,   
 zmin=0,
 zmax=1200,          
         xtick={0,10},
 xticklabels={{10},{0}},
  ytick={0,10},
   ztick={0,1200},
 ,colormap/blackwhite, rotate around z=20
    ]

    \addplot3+[mesh,scatter,samples=10,domain=0:10] 
        {y^3};

\addplot3 [data cs=cart,surf,domain=0:10,samples=2, opacity=0.5]
      {x^3};        

    \end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You use `samples=2` in the second plot. Use e.g. `samples=21` to get something nonlinear.

Comment: Thx for pointing out